# Changing XML List name for String after a webservice invoke

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-services

ok with the suggestion now the output is

```
<picture>11000covcl_2.jpg</picture>
<picture>11000covcl_3.jpg</picture>
<picture>11000covcl_4.jpg</picture>
```

I would like to look like this

```
<picture_list>
   <picture>....</picture>
</picture_list>
```

this is c# code im using

```
sqlCommand = "{CALL getPictureList(?)}";
sqlParamList = new String[,] { { "@ProductID", prodID } };
OdbcDataReader pDataReader = null;
pDataReader = odbcConnection.executeStoreProcReader(sqlCommand, sqlParamList);
item.picture_list = new List<string>();

while (pDataReader.Read())
{ 
    item.picture_list.Add(pDataReader.GetString(0));
}

pDataReader.Close();
itemList.Add(item);
```

Pls let me know if anyone needs more explaination

Comment: Is this an ASMX web service or a WCF service?

Comment: Well, you can also use struct and return it in webmethod. It will show the tag as of the elements in struct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
public class YourObject
{
     [XmlArray("picture_list")]  
     [XmlArrayItem("picture")]
     public List<string> picture_list { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have access to the class where property "picture_list" is defined, you simply need to decorate the picture_list property with the XmlElement attribute like so:

EDIT: also assuming you are using the XmlSerializer. If not, please clarify the serializer you are using.

```
public class YourObject
{   
     [XmlElement("picture")]
     public List<string> picture_list { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: works except it doesnt keep it nested under <picture_list><picture>11000covcl_2.jpg</picture>
<picture>11000covcl_3.jpg</picture>
<picture>11000covcl_4.jpg</picture>

Comment: using System.Xml.Serialization;